# why does $2^{\log_2c} = c$

Tags: logarithms

Reviewing some basic properties log logs.
why does $2^{\log_2c} = c$?
I understand that $\log_2c$ is basically $2$ to some power = $c$, but I'm not sure why the above expression is equal to $c$.
thanks!

Comment: " I understand that log2c is basically 2 to some power = c"  That's all there is to it!  $\log_2 c$ is the "some power" needed to raise $2$ to in order to get $c$.  And if you raise $2$ to the power you need to raise $2$ to in order to get $2$... you'd better expect to get $2$.  (Otherwise it *wasn't* the power needed!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log_2 c$ is defined as the unique number $u$ such that $2^u = c.$ Therefore $2^{\log_2 c} = c.$

Answer (score 2):

$\log _2 c = a$ for some $a$ if $2^a =c$. Hence $2^a =c$ and $2^{\log_2 c}=c$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $b>0$, $\log_b x$ is the inverse function of the function $b^x$, and, as is the case for all inverse functions,
$$f\circ f^{-1}=\operatorname{id}, \enspace\text{so }\quad b^{\log_b(x)}=x\enspace\text{and}\enspace\log_b(b^x)=x.$$

Answer (score 1):

The exponential and logarithmic functions have an inverse relation; that is to say, $$f(x)=b^x\iff f^{-1}(x)=\log_b(x).$$
As such, remembering what you know about functions and their inverses, it is easy to see why you have what you have:  $$(f\circ f^{-1})(x)=x$$

Let $f(c)=2^c$.  Therefore, $f^{-1}(c)=\log_2c$, and $2^{\log_2c}=c$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $k= \log_2 c$ is the solution to $2^k = c$.

So if $2^{\log_2 c} \ne 2$ then $k= \log_2 c$ is *NOT* the solution to $2^k = c$.